# How to get values from unknown key in NSDictionary iphone?

Tags: iphone, web-services, nsdictionary

I have one more big problem while parse the values from Webservice response. I dont know the key for the values in the webservice response. For example,

```
class =     (
                {
            "ObjectiveC" =   
         (
                                {
                    "brief_desc" = "ObjectiveC";
                    date = "2008-02-27";
                    "event_status" = Attended;
                },
                                {
                    "brief_desc" = "ObjectiveC";
                    date = "2008-03-05";
                    "event_status" = Attended;
                },
                                {
                    "brief_desc" = "ObjectiveC";
                    date = "2008-03-12";
                    "event_status" = Missed;
                },
            ); 
        },
                {
            "Java" =             (
 {
                    "brief_desc" = "Java";
                    date = "2008-02-27";
                    "event_status" = Attended;
                },
                                {
                    "brief_desc" = "Java";
                    date = "2008-03-05";
                    "event_status" = Attended;
                },
                                {
                    "brief_desc" = "Java";
                    date = "2008-03-12";
                    "event_status" = Missed;
                },
            );
        }
    );
```

In this response even we dont know the keys "ObjectiveC" and "Java". The keys("ObjectiveC and Java") should be change in every response retured. How to get values of key (Unknown key)? How can i parse this response and get the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would enumerate through the keys to get the value. Here is an example of enumeration in objective-c.

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [myDictionary keyEnumerator];
id key;
while ((key = [enumerator nextObject])) {
    //assuming value will be string
    NSString *valueForKey = [myDictionary valueForKey:key]; 

    //assuming value is another dictionary
    NSDictionary *subDictionary = [myDictionary objectForKey:key];
}
```

And if you don't know the keys of the sub dictionaries, you can enumerate through those as well.

Answer (score 3):

NSDictionary has `- (NSArray *)allKeys` and `- (NSArray *)allValues`. One of those might help

```
NSDictionary * lessonDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Key", @"Value", @"Key 2", @"Value 2", nil];
    NSArray *values = [lessonDict allValues];

    NSArray *keys = [lessonDict allKeys];
    NSLog(@"Keys: %@",keys);
    NSLog(@"Values: %@",values);
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Syclonefx. I have also used this code to retrieve the keys but it failed. NSMutableDictionary *lessonDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    lessonDictionary = [invoiceDic valueForKey:@"class"];
    NSLog(@"Lesson Dic : %@, count : %d", lessonDictionary, [lessonDictionary count]);
    
    for (id key in [lessonDictionary allkeys]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Key : %@", key);
    }   I have tried this code, but the app getting crash in for(id key in [lessonDictionary allkeys]) line.

Comment: Thanks. i have used your last suggestion but, it show warning "Instance method'-allkeys:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')" and the app getting crash in this line "[keys allKeys:lessonDicti]". I received the crash reason in debugger console "+[sampleScreen allKeys:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x8fa98". Sorry for the disturbance. Please help to fix this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah the code I posted in the previous comment was wrong. I updated the my answer with the correct code.